# Modify server in /etc/ntp.conf with one-liner?

Tags: linux, augeas

In `/etc/ntp.conf` would I like to change all servers to just

```
server ntp.example.com
```

in just one command line.

I can do it with ssh like so

```
augtool --autosave --noautoload --transform "ssh incl /etc/ssh/ssh_config" set "/files/etc/ssh/ssh_config/ServerAliveInterval" 60
```

Can something similar be done for `server` in `/etc/ntp.conf`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering there are likely more than one `server` entries in your file originally, you need two commands to achieve this:

```
rm /files/etc/ntp.conf/server
set /files/etc/ntp.conf/server ntp.example.com
```

and `augtool` can only take one command as a one-liner.

What you can do however is to use stdin for this, e.g.:

```
echo -e "rm /files/etc/ntp.conf/server\nset /files/etc/ntp.conf/server ntp.example.com" | augtool -sAt "Ntp incl /etc/ntp.conf"
```